# Symfony 2.4 {{app.request}} is empty in Production

Tags: symfony, twig, production-environment

I'm using `app.request` for various and common usages as retrieving locale, current route, etc.

```
{{ path(app.request.get('_route')) }}
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

It works fine in `Development` environment, but in `Production` the variable is simply empty. It returns always `null` values, so it results on all kind of errors like:

```
"Unable to generate a URL for the named route "" as such route does not exist."
```

How can I access `app.request` in `Production` environment?

#### Edit

I should clarify that `app.request` actually "exists", but for some reason it returns always empty values instead of the expected ones. If I call a nonexistent method under `app.request`, for instance `app.request.thisdoesnotexist` I get an error:

```
Method "thisdoesnotexist" for object "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" does not exist in...
```

But I'm not getting this error, so `app.request` is actually defined, but empty.

Comment: Have you tested on several pages? Maybe the `_route` is empty on the homepage only.

Comment: Yes, I've tested. And it's not only `_route`, but any `app.request` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution. It was a deployment issue with my particular setup, but it could help others in similar situations.

To shorten: rebuild your `bootstrap.php` with

```
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

If for any reason you are forced to run `composer` updates in `Production` with the `--no-scripts` option (as I am due to shared hosting restrictions), forgetting to rebuild that file can cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`app.request` work in any environment. But you missed a `)`:

```
{{ path('"'~app.request.get('_route')~'"') }}
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

Or try to test :

```
{{ app.request.get('_route') }}
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's a typo in the question, not in my actual code. So it still fails.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm getting no error related to syntax or `app.request` itself, I just get a `null` value that triggers errors when used. Like `{{ path(app.request.get('_route')) }}` = `{{ path("") }}` = `ERROR`

Comment: Finally I've found a solution myself, the problem was too localized for a general approach. I'll post an answer, but thanks a lot anyway!